# Android Custom layout in gallery

Tags: android, android-gallery

Hi i am putting custom layout in Android 'GalleryView' i have following code in my getview() method.
But its giving Exception **The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView()** Please help.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
            ll.setId(position*9);
            ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            int padding = (int) Math.round( 2.5*density);


            ll.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

            ImageView iv = new ImageView(mContext);
            iv= chanelViewArrayList.get(position).snapshotImageView;
            iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(Math.round(100*density),Math.round(100*density)));
            iv.setId(position);


            ll.removeAllViews();
            ll.addView(iv);
       return ll;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 iv= chanelViewArrayList.get(position).snapshotImageView;
```

is same for more that one positions . you can not add a view which is already added somewhere . 
so insure that this method returns fresh view for every child .

paste code if possible .

Comment: **position**  is parameter from getView() method. so different view is coming for different item, am i right?

Comment: for example once position=1 , its view added , but when again getview will be called for position=1, will give error . so instead of store them somewhere else and add to linealLayout create them dinamicaaly . best choice in inflate from xml

Comment: My app is downloading the images asynchronously. so I assigned it to ImageView i.e. After download complete ImageView will get visible. So any idea to skip error. Please help

Comment: so maintain an array of bitmap's .and fill in asynchronosly . pick aray[position] in getView . it will avoid repetitive server requests .